# Appropriate approach to track database changes in a .Net Core Web API and send corresponding push notification to client using SignalR

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a project in .net core 5 Web API which is using EF Core as ORM. I would like to send notification to specific/all clients whenever any successful insert/update/delete is performed on specific tables in the database. This Web API project would be the only way to access the database.

To send push notification, I am using SignalR.

Due to performance related issues I do not intend to use trigger, change tracker etc mechanisms that are directly associated with the database.

Any action method in my web api controller would have the following flow -

```
EmployeeService : BaseService {
...
}

EmployeeController:BaseController {

private EmployeeService empService;
...

[HttpPost] 
public Task<EmployeeDto> EditEmployee(Guid id, EmployeeUpdateDto model)  {
....

   // Here I call the corresponding method in EmployeeService which in turn calls appropriate
   // Repository method
..

}


}
```

So in controller method , after the appropriate service call, I would be able to understand whether the table has been actually updated or not and accordingly I can call SignlaR to send push notification.

My query is whether this is the best approach to handle the scenario ?
And if it is the best approach then shall I use a ResultFilter or another service (that I inject in Every Controller ) to send the SignalR notification.

In case this approach does not seem to be an efficient one, please suggest how can I achieve the same in an alternate manner.

Comment: Do you mean you will use signlar method inside each method to push notification to the client-side? Does this web api is just used for some specific client application which is built by you? Normally, if this web api will be used by different application, we will not add signalr method inside it, since some client will not include the signlar service. Normally. for the web api, we will just include the web api related method which will just return the json result. Then we could return some successfully result to the client side to let the client side show the action successfully or not.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Webapi would return value. In.my case I would like to also send push notification from the web api when specific (not all) tables are updated. I would like to know best way to use a service/filter to get notified when these specific tables are modified and send the modified data to the client so that client UI can be updated real-time.

Comment: There's nothing wrong to use change tracker for this,  what's your problem with it?

Comment: What I understand is that,  change tracker does impact performance .. that is why looking for mechanism that is not directly related to the database.

Comment: And you measurements say the impact is how much %/ms??!

Comment: https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/improve-entity-framework-core-performance

Comment: There are multiple such articles which makes it very clear that change tracking does come with a performance cost.    In case you think, the approach that I described in my post will not be able to match the performance of change tracking mechanism or those approaches are not appropriate for the intended task please enlighten me.